# hasClass() function not detecting -- preceding function won't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following function:

```
var imgs = $('img');
if ($(imgs).hasClass('cboxPhoto')) {
  imgs.each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    var width = img.width();
    var height = img.height();
    if (width < height) {
      img.addClass('relative');
    } else {
      img.removeClass('relative');
    }
  });
}
```

I am essentially trying to state if an `<img>` has the class of "cboxPhoto" then run the each() function is for detecting the height & width and add the class of "relative" if the image width is greater than it's height.

I've ran for errors, but nothing comes up. Is it because I am trying to detect within the same element? Should there be a parent element? I thought it might be because the image parameters aren't set for the jQuery to even detect it, thus the function won't run?

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/b0rL3vs4/2/

Comment: dont put a dot (period) in the class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `addClass()` ,  `removeClass()` or `hasClass()` you do not use a period , just use the class name ex:

```
.hasClass('cboxPhoto')
```

see jQuery docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

> className
>   Type: String
>   The class name to search for.

```
$( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "foo" )
```

no errors are going to show up, it is still valid code , but it wil never find the class name you are looking for

### UPDATE

see your code :

```
var imgs = $('img');
if ($(img).hasClass('cboxPhoto')) {
```

you have not defined `img` at this line

Comment: I updated it without the dot, however, the function does not seem to run.

Comment: updated answer with another bug I found in your code

Comment: Something, so simple, always great for another pair of eyes. Thanks for the help. Answer accepted.

Comment: Accepting when timer is up.